# Use Debian Laptop as Bluetooth headset?

Tags: audio, bluetooth, qt, bluez, telephony

I want to use my laptop (Debian 8.4) as a bluetooth headset for my smartphone (OnePlus One, Android). This means not just audio of my phone, also incoming calls.

I already managed to play normal audio over the laptop speakers, but no telephone data. I saw there is a headset profile for bluetooth. Does it work automatically? I already had worked with PBAP and MAP, but in the bluetooth headset specification i found no helping answers.

I set the bluetooth class of my laptop to `0x40040C` in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and also set it via

```
hciconfig hci0 class 0x40040C
```

The class I get from [this website](http://bluetooth-pentest.narod.ru/software/bluetooth_class_of_device-service_generator.html).

To connect it I use `bluetoothctl`. But when I change the modus (eg. discoverable on), the laptop always changes its bluetooth class back to laptop.

When I am searching for devices at my phone, the laptop appears with a headset icon, but when I pair, the icon changes to a regular headphone icon. In the settings there is also 'Media Audio'. What I think I need is 'Telephone Audio'. So the question is, how can I achieve this?

It would be great if I heave no extra (graphical) tools to install and even better when there is some code to get it work in QT. All examples I have found do not work, are for Windows or are too old. In my case receiving a message per bluetooth that a call is incoming would be enough (like a simple smartwatch, just showing).

With my current solution with media audio, I hear just the phone ringing, on laptop and phone simultaneously, but just if I set the telephone sound on my phone from silent or vibration to any volume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst having `connected` for media purposes, I'd suggest you to try receving a call on your phone or dial a number.

Most of the recent Android versions, provide an option to use your `Telephone Audio` through your `already connected bluetooth speakers` on a calling screen once you touch the `speakerphone toggle icon`.

There shouldn't have been an explicit need of configuring it further.

Probable reason the icon reverts could be the `bluetoothctl` detects that you haven't got a way to receive a call *through your desktop* (Portable Bluetooth speakers mostly have the receive-a-call hardware button for the same.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I get a call when connected to media, but still the calling sound was coming from the laptop speakers. I know this option from my car radio, but sadly there was no possibility to change it from phone speaker to laptop speaker. Is there a way to simulate this button programmatically?

Answer (score 5):

I've solved in this way:

install `ofono`

in `/etc/pulse/default.pa` find the line `load-module module-bluetooth-discover` and change it in `load-module module-bluetooth-discover headset=ofono`

Add the user `pulse` to group `bluetooth` to grant the permission: `sudo useradd -g bluetooth pulse` (probably it's already correct)

VERY IMPORTANT: To grant the permission, add this to `/etc/dbus-1/system.d/ofono.conf` (before /busconfig> ;-)):

```
<policy user="pulse">  
<allow send_destination="org.ofono"/>
</policy>
```

See: https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Bluetooth/

The good news: Now in pavucontrol I can see that the profile changes automatically from A2DP to HSP / HFP if I make a phone call, and then it magically returns to A2DP!

The bad news: it works only one time per booting (and checking if ofonod is running), then I have to reboot my Debian system.